# Looking for C# Google Safe Browsing LOOKUP API Client

Tags: c#, rest

Is there any client or a way to use the existing google API client to consume the 
Google Safe Browsing Lookup API service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any pre-built API library for the Google Safe Browsing Lookup API service, but RestSharp (http://restsharp.org/) would help you consume the API.

Comment: Is very easy to consume using restsharp. Thanks for the tip!